# EF - Join Query using a Id parameter from controller with where clause

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, linq

I have two tables, operation code and sub operation codes, and I need to return all sub codes of each code, with only sub codes that are active

```
public class OperationCode: Entity
{ 
    public guid Id.
    public bool Active{ get; set; }
    public bool Excluded{ get; set; }
    public string Code { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<SubOperationCode> SubOperationCode{ get; set; }
}

public class SubOperationCode: Entity
{
    public guid Id.
    public bool Active{ get; set; }
    public bool Excluded{ get; set; }
    public string Code { get; set; }
    public virtual OperationCode OperationCode{ get; set; }
 }
```

i try using something like that, but it did not work

```
public override OperationCode getById(Guid id)
{
      var result = Db.SubOperationCode.Join(Db.OperationCode,
            sub => sub.Id == id,
            code => code.Id,
            (sub, code) => new { sub, code }).toList();
      return result 
 }
```

Comment: If you are using `DBContext` and the `Db.SubOperationCode` is `DBSet<SubOperationCode>`, `Db.SubOperationCode.Include("OperationCode").Where((q) => q.Id == id)` will be enough to provide you that. Though, you may want to adjust the `Where`

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a JOIN - use your navigation properties then project to a result list (anonymous in this case, but could be a model).

```
var operationsWithActiveSubOps = Db.OperationCodes
     .Include(o => o.SubOperationCode)
     .Select(o => new {
          OperationId = o.Id,
          OperationCode = o.Code,
          ActiveSubOperations = o.SubOperationCode.Where(so => so.Active)
     })
     .ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following

```
public override OperationCode getById(Guid id)
{
  var result = Db.SubOperationCode.Join(Db.OperationCode,
        sub => sub.Id,
        code => code.Id,
        (sub, code) => new { sub, code })
        Where(x => sub.Id == id).toList();
  return result 
}
```

Comment: Should't `Where(x => sub.Id == id)` be `Where(x => x.sub.Id == id)`?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this one:

```
public override OperationCode getById(Guid id)
{
    return Db.OperationCode.Include(o => o.SubOperationCode)
        .FirstOrDefault(o => o.Id == id && o.SubOperationCode.Any(so => so.Active))
}
```